# filter dataframe on each value of a samn column have a specific value of another column in Panda\Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to find the animal which have brown color (column 'color') and for those animals keep all the information about it (all the rows), and for the animals which have not brown colour, delete all informations about it (all the rows).

Any insight?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['dog','France','white'],['dog','Japon','brown'],['cat','France','white'],['cat','France','dark']],columns=['Animal','localisation','couleur'])

output = pd.DataFrame([['dog','France','white'],['dog','Japon','brown']],columns=['Animal','localisation','couleur'])
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you have tried so far? You will get useful responses if you show some effort rather than expect people to solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter`

```
In [4934]: df.groupby('Animal').filter(lambda x: 'brown' in x['couleur'].values)
Out[4934]:
  Animal localisation couleur
0    dog       France   white
1    dog        Japon   brown
```

Or

```
In [4935]: df.groupby('Animal').filter(lambda x: x['couleur'].eq('brown').any())
Out[4935]:
  Animal localisation couleur
0    dog       France   white
1    dog        Japon   brown
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply a condition `df['couleur'] == 'brown]` to get only the records where the couleur field is brown, and then overwrite the original dataframe (to delete):

```
df = df[df['couleur'] == 'brown']
```

or if you just want the output:

```
output = df[df['couleur'] == 'brown']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter based on the color and then extract the list of animals that remain, and then filter your original dataframe for animals in that list, using the pd.Series.isin method:

```
animals = df[df['couleur'] == 'brown']['Animal']
output = df[df['Animal'].isin(animals)]
```

or in one line:

```
output = df[df['Animal'].isin(df[df['couleur'] == 'brown']['Animal'])]
```